# Specifying failover servers in c# webservice client

Tags: c#, dns, failover, webservice-client, mission-critical

I need to build in some resilience in a web service client application. Are any of these two scenarios supported by the standard dot.net web service generated client (classic or 3.0)?

- Specifying a list of server addresses so that the clien can fall back automatically if one server goes down.
- Configuring the client so it looks up the DNS Service records instead of the standard hosts and uses the lists of host by priority, keeping track of which hosts are up.

Load balancing the server or going through a proxy does not solve my problem, which is related to geographical resilience.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've generally built our own layer; I don't think the default generated client code does anything like this.

More often, we define a custom configSection and then add a bunch of key/value pairs in that section.  Then, we round-robin through that list for each request.